# users notification in rails

Tags: notifications, ruby-on-rails-4

i have an application am designing which consists of users making friends and users 
having many posts, paintings, friends and talks
the model is below

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


  has_many :paintings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :sells, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :talks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :friends
  has_many :comments
end
```

i have set a notification system in which when a user creates a post or painting e.t.c 
a notification is sent to the users friends which i have achieved with public_activity gem,

what i intend to achieve is a notification system in which when the notification is created, every user involved can mark as seen i.e they have seen it so THAT notification is not shown to the user anymore... And also when a user comments on a notification, i want a notification to be sent to the owner of the activity, and any other user that comments on THAT notification...    IN SUMMARY, I NEED A FACEBOOK LIKE NOTIFACATION SYSTEM...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a Notification after the relevant post/painting has been added?

Notifications would be created (probably using an after_create action on each of the relevant models e.g. posts, paintings).

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_create :create_notification

 private

  def create_notification
    # create notification here
  end
end
```

If there are lots of notifications to be created then you may wish to consider creating them in a background job.

A notification would belong to the target friend of the user and could therefore be marked as seen through an attribute on the notification. You would include instance methods on the notification object to deal with this.

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user # friend of the originating user

 def mark_seen
   update_attributes(viewed: true)
 end

end
```

You could also add scopes on the notifications to make sure that users can easily see unseen notifications.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :unseen_notifications, conditions: "notifications.viewed IS false" #or something like that
end
```

Hope this helps to set you on the right track.

Comment: thanks for your fast response and i want you to help me out with this

Comment: thanks for your fast response and i want you to help me out with this the comment notification too so its displayed to the owner of the activity and the user who comments too

Comment: Just like we did for the Post model you could also add an after_create action for the Comment model so that a Notification is always created after a Comment is saved. In fact, you could do this for each of the models that required a notification (you could even be more advanced and extract the after_create action for each of the model that require notifications into a model concern!) This would help to keep you code nice and DRY.

Comment: it works only that it sends the notification to all friends instead of only users that commented on the activity let me show you some of my code   @activities = Activity.where(user_id: [current_user.friend_ids, current_user]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)   this is responsible for the activity to be shown to the user and the friends only. what if i want the activity to be shown to the user and who ever comments on the activity only

Comment: I think the best thing to do would be to make sure that each Activity has the right user_id attached to it for whether it is the current user, one of their friends or a commenter. You could then create a class method on Activity to further refine the activities returned (based upon the user_id of the comment)

Comment: could you elaborate more .... i would be glad thanks maybe sort of an example thamks again